# How to perform some processing on a livedata before returning it

Tags: java, android, android-livedata

How can I do to update the result of the LiveData (from Room Dao) before returning it ?

In my viewmodel:

```
public LiveData<List<Article>> getAllArticle(long clistId) {
    return articleDataSource.getAll(clistId);
}
```

I need to make a treatement:

```
for (int i=0; i<articles.size(); i++) {
    articles.get(i).setOrd(i);
}
```

I thought I had to use Transformations.map but I can't.

Comment: What do you mean that you can't?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, when I try again, it works as expected.
So I'm posting my solution in case it might help someone else.

```
public LiveData<List<Article>> getAllArticle(long clistId) {
    return Transformations.map(articleDataSource.getAll(clistId), articles -> {
        for (int i=0; i<articles.size(); i++) {
            articles.get(i).setOrd(i);
        }
        updateAllArticles(articles);
        return articles;
    });
}
```